# How can I disable Chrome DNS caching?

Tags: google-chrome, caching, dns

I'd like to disable Chrome from performing DNS caching.
Is there a way to do that through configuration or registry changes (like it is possible for IE and Firefox) ?

Comment: You can clear the cache at chrome://net-internals/#dns, but there doesn't seem to be a way to prevent caching in the first place.

Comment: @Barmar: I'm looking for a configuration setting or something I can do programatically by another application

Comment: This question belongs to #superuser and yes: I've the same problem

Comment: Me too. It causes intermittent delay in loading pages.